# Compiling android .apk by java code

Tags: java, android

I would like to create a java app that actually programaticlly compiles a differnt android project - Meaning i'd like to create .apk files by code. How would i go about this??? Is this feasible?

Thanks

Comment: If you want it to run on the Android device, I'd say it's not feasible.  If you want it to run on a workstation (i.e., replicate Dalvik) it's feasible but why would you need it?

Comment: No no, i mean compile a custom android package from a java "console application", Not on an android device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it could be done. If there is a way to build an Android project by command line, you can make those calls with Java I'm sure. See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html) and [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html) link for information on building Android programs from the command line. From there, its simply invoking the correct commands in Java, maybe using [Runtime.exec](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29)().

This will require a good understanding of the build process, and will most likely get very cumbersome. So an answer to your question as to whether or not it is feasible: no, it would be difficult.

You could use [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) to automate your build process.